# How to add Azure AD Cloud Connect Provisioned users to the Azure Exchange GAL

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

### SCENARIO

We are using Azure AD Cloud Provisioning Agent (the new lightweight Azure AD Connect agent in public preview) to import users from remote forest into existing Azure AD.
Their accounts have the email attribute set to their respective email hosted elsewhere.

Existing AzureAD is syncronizing own forest AD through ordinary Azure AD Connect.
These users are fully Office365 users with mailboxes.

### QUESTION

How do we achieve the users from remote AD get added to the Exchange GAL so that users from own forest can look them up in Outlook?

Do we have to assign an Office365 license to the remote AD users and somehow mail-enable them (and possibly create some customisation in Azure Exchange)?

Or do we simply create them as Contacts in Azure Exchange manually? (through some automation of course)

Any insights would be greatly appreciated.

/Simon

Comment: Not even Microsoft can answer me this ;(